# nodejs, Cannot find module './connection/read_preference' error with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to run tests on an app created by a collegue and keep getting this error. The call is in the mongodb module on line 13

```
ReadPreference = require('./connection/read_preference').ReadPreference,
```

Have you any idea on why this happens?I Have mongo db running correctly.

Comment: Do you have the latest install of the driver?  Whats the full error trace.

Comment: @Ross it was an issue with mongoskin module, i removed / reinstalled it and everything works

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue with mongoskin.

```
npm remove mongoskin

npm install mogoskin
```

solved it